# wix: ICE57 and ICE91 warnings for perUser installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using [wix](http://wix.sf.net) 3.5 to author a windows installer with the "perUser" install scope. The [wxs file is here](http://bitbucket.org/wcoenen/downmarker/src/45365698dded/setup/product.wxs), the resulting [MSI file is here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/119154/permalink/downmarker.msi).

I get the following strange warnings from the `light.exe` linker. I'm not sure if I should just suppress them or if there is some better way to fix this.

**ICE57**

> D:\hg\downmarker\setup\product.wxs(34)
>   : warning LGHT1076 : ICE57: Component
>   'component.downmarker.exe' has both
>   per-user and per-machine data with an
>   HKCU Registry KeyPath.

This warning doesn't make sense to me, because the installer works fine without administrative access - which AFAIK proves that the installer doesn't write any "per-machine data" as the warning claims.

**ICE91**

> D:\hg\downmarker\setup\product.wxs(37)
>   : warning LGHT1076 : ICE91: The file
>   'downmarker.exe' will be installed to
>   the per user directory
>   'DownMarkerFolder' that  doesn't vary
>   based on ALLUSERS value. This file
>   won't be copied to each user's profile
>   even if a per machine installation is
>   desired.

This warning doesn't make sense to me either because I explicitly mark the installer as having the "perUser" install scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ICE57 is shown because component "component.downmarker.exe" contains registry entries from HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is per-machine, so the component has both per-user and per-machine data.

I noticed you are using HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for a file association. You can use "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes" instead to obtain a per-user file association.

ICE91 is harmless and can be ignored for per-user installations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369053(VS.85).aspx

Comment: +1 Thanks for ICE91 link, that's reassuring. For ICE57: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` already maps to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes` in a per-user context, it is not always per-machine. Otherwise I would not be able to run my installer without admin priviliges. Also, if I follow your suggestion to explicitly write to `HKCU\Software\Classes` instead then I still get the warning, perhaps because the `ProgId` element implicitly uses `HKCR`.